# Jacobian of a dot product

Tags: derivatives, jacobian

An online video showed me that:
$$ J(a \cdot b) = a^{T} J(b) + b^{T} J(a) $$
for a,b being vectors.
But my question is: isn't the dot product a scalar? So isn't the jacobian of a scalar just 0?

Video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8oIjsBBljA at 3:00

Answer (score 1):

(1) true, (2) false. Scalar $=$ 1D $\ne$ constant.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/788969)

Comment: @ClémentGuérin, seriously? The OP asks two questions: "isn't the dot product a scalar?" (true); "isn't the jacobian of a scalar just 0?" (false because scalar $\ne$ constant).

Comment: Ok this does provide an answer to the question. I just wish you had given one or two explanations to the OP about your (correct) answer. This kind of answer looks like a comment to me.

Answer (score 1):

The source of confusion here is the meaning of 'the Jacobian.'

The most familiar instance in which one sees this term is the $n$-variable substitution rule, and there the Jacobian is often taken to be the determinant of an $n$-by-$n$ matrix of partial derivatives. This definition only makes since if a the argument of the Jacobian is an $n$-vector of scalar functions. As a consequence, the formula you cite would be clearly false under this definition.

However, you will also see the Jacobian defined as the *matrix* of first partial derivatives. In this case, the argument can be any $m$-vector and the result will be some rectangular $m$-by-$n$ matrix. In particular this works for a single scalar function and yields the formula cited.

Comment: The problem/confusion of the OP is in the question "isn't the jacobian of a scalar just 0?"